# Scrape page, fetch images and generate folder with images per page scraped

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, dictionary

I'm fetching list of images from pages scraped with selenium web driver.
For each page there is `n` images, each image has 3 variants (thumb, hoved, full).
So I created list where each list item is dictionary with all 3 versions of image:

```
advert_image_dict.append({
            'Image_thumb_100x75:': img,
            'Image_hoved_400x300:': image_hoved,
            'Image_full_800x600:': image_full})
```

so individual list items look like this:

```
print(image_dict[1])

{'Image_thumb_100x75:':
'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801_thumb.jpg', 
'Image_hoved_400x300:':
'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801_hoved.jpg', 
'Image_full_800x600:':
'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801.jpg'}
```

I need to create folder per web page scraped which will hold all images for that page.
Folder name is formed like this: `{Page_#x}{Title of page}`
and each folder contains fetched images from that page.
Image names are in form:

```
{Title of page}{Image_#x}{image_dict[x].get('Image_thumb_100x75')}
{Title of page}{Image_#x}{image_dict[x].get('Image_hoved_400x300')}
{Title of page}{Image_#x}{image_dict[x].get('Image_full_800x600')}

{Title of page}{Image_#x+1}{image_dict[x+1].get('Image_thumb_100x75')}
{Title of page}{Image_#x+1}{image_dict[x+1].get('Image_hoved_400x300')}
{Title of page}{Image_#x+1}{image_dict[x+1].get('Image_full_800x600')}
```

Variable `ad_title` holds title (I'll remove spaces and other chars).

I would create folders per page with

```
path = "/test/`{Page_#x}{Title of page}"
os.mkdir(path)
```

and fetch individual images in that folder with

```
urllib.urlretrieve("https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801_thumb.jpg", "{Title of page}{Image_#x}{image_dict[x].get('Image_thumb_100x75')}")
```

I just don't know how to define this fetch/define-names iterator for folders and image names.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like simple string formatting could help you here.

To build the name and path of the folder, you could use:

```
import os

page_num = 22
page_title = 'something'
dir_name = '{}{}'.format(page_num, page_title)
dir_full_path = os.path.join('/', 'test', dir_name)
```

To build the names of the image files, you could try:

```
advert_image_list = [
    {
        'Image_thumb_100x75:': 'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801_thumb.jpg',
        'Image_hoved_400x300:': 'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801_hoved.jpg',
        'Image_full_800x600:': 'https://cache.mysite.com/mmo/7/295/170/227_-64694801.jpg',
    },
    ...
]

for i, d in enumerate(advert_image_list):
    file_name_1 = '{}{}{}'.format(page_title, i, d['Image_thumb_100x75'])
    file_name_2 = '{}{}{}'.format(page_title, i, d['Image_hoved_400x300'])
    file_name_3 = '{}{}{}'.format(page_title, i, d['Image_full_800x600'])
```

Does this help you?

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!